# Is R/I an integral domain or Non commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be its ideal defined by $R=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]: a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$
and
$I=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{ll}0 & a \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]: a \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ then $R / I$ is

1. an integral domain but not a field.
2. not an integral domain.
3. field
4. non-commutative ring.

My Attempt:

Here $R$ is a non-commutative ring. $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.

> Let $\mathrm{R}$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $\mathrm{M}$ be an ideal of $\mathrm{R}$. Then the factor ring $\mathrm{R} / \mathrm{M}$ is a field if and only if $\mathrm{M}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathrm{R}$

Here I can't use this theorem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : An element in $R/I$ looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix} + I = \begin{pmatrix} 
a & 0 \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix} + I
$$
So $R/I $ consists of elements of type $\begin{pmatrix} 
a & 0 \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix} + I$
for each $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hope you can figure it now.